# Avoid adding duplicate values

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

I have this method for adding in a table from another database same values that comes from another database:

```
public function insert()
{
    $indexes= DB::connection('sqlsrv')
            ->select
            (
            "
            IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[test].[dbo].[indexes]') AND type in (N'U'))
            CREATE TABLE test.dbo.indexes 
                (
                    table_view nvarchar(500) not null,
                    [columns] nvarchar(500) not null,
                    [type] nvarchar(50) not null,
                    index_name nvarchar(500) not null,
                    index_id int not null
                )
            insert into test.dbo.indexes (table_view, [columns], [type], index_name, index_id)

            select 
            schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view,
            substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns],
            case when i.is_primary_key = 1 then 'Primary_key'
            when i.is_unique = 1 then 'Unique'
            else 'Not_unique' end as [type],
            i.[name] as index_mane,
            i.index_id
            from sys.objects t
            inner join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
            cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                from sys.index_columns ic
                    inner join sys.columns col
                        on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                        and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                    and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        order by col.column_id
                        for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
            where t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
            and index_id > 0
            order by schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name], i.index_id
            "
            );
}
```

The problem is that when I run this multiple times the records are being duplicated. What can I do to stop this? I need that, when I run this for the second, third, X time to add only what is not the same.

Comment: I am not trying to copy something from a table to another, I am trying to put the result of that select in the table that I create at beginning of script, so that is not working

Comment: tried that, but didn't worked, maybe I didn't knew where to add this line since I am learning :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `not exists` condition to test for duplicates as shown below.

```sql
insert into test.dbo.indexes (table_view, [columns], [type], index_name, index_id)
select table_view, [columns], [type], index_name, index_id
from (
    select 
        schema_name(t.[schema_id]) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view
        , substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns]
        , case when i.is_primary_key = 1 then 'Primary_key'
            when i.is_unique = 1 then 'Unique'
            else 'Not_unique' end as [type]
        , i.[name] as index_name
        , i.index_id
    from sys.objects t
    inner join sys.indexes i
    on t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
    cross apply (
        select col.[name] + ', '
        from sys.index_columns ic
        inner join sys.columns col on ic.[object_id] = col.[object_id] and ic.column_id = col.column_id
        where ic.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        and ic.index_id = i.index_id
        order by col.column_id
        for xml path ('')
    ) D (column_names)
    where t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    and index_id > 0
) X
-- The following where clause prevents the insertion of duplicates
where not exists (
    select 1
    from test.dbo.indexes I
    where I.table_view = X.table_view and I.[columns] = X.[columns] and I.[type] = X.[type] and I.index_name = X.index_name and I.index_id = X.index_id
);
```

Note: There is no benefit to adding an `order by` to an `insert` statement, tables are inherently unordered, you must use `order by` on your select if order matters.